# Flake8 gives F832 Undefined Name despite using "from __future__ import annotations"

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, flake8, python-3.10

I have this `pyi` file.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import datetime


class Payment:
    amount: float = ...
    date: datetime.date = ...

    def set_amount(self: Payment, amount: float = Amounts.Null):
        ...

    def get_amount(self: Payment) -> float:
        ...

    def get_date(self: Payment) -> datetime.date:
        ...


class Amounts:
    Null: float = ...
```

Using `from __future__ import annotations` helps remove the `F821 undefined name 'Payment'` warnings for the `self` arguments.

However, flake8 still shows `F821 undefined name 'Amounts'`. Can this warning be fixed somehow (without disabling F821 entirely)? Or it this a bug perhaps?

---

Note, I am using `flake8 4.0.1 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.8.0, pyflakes: 2.4.0)` on `Python 3.10.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is not wrong:

```
$ python3 t.pyi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.pyi", line 5, in <module>
    class Payment:
  File "t.pyi", line 9, in Payment
    def set_amount(self: Payment, amount: float = Amounts.Null):
NameError: name 'Amounts' is not defined
```

`__future__` `annotations` defers **annotations** but you've got a default value (which is not an annotation!) referring to a class later in the file

one option is a simple reordering:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import datetime


class Amounts:
    Null: float = ...


class Payment:
    amount: float = ...
    date: datetime.date = ...

    def set_amount(self: Payment, amount: float = Amounts.Null):
        ...

# ...
```

even better is to omit the default value entirely, since it does nothing in a pyi (or stub function):

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import datetime


class Payment:
    amount: float = ...
    date: datetime.date = ...

    def set_amount(self: Payment, amount: float = ...):

# ...
```

note also that your function is subtly incorrect -- right now a type checker will interpret `set_amount` as `-> Any` because you omit the return value, the correct thing to do there is `-> None`

the other route you can take is to ignore the errors via `# noqa`, `per-file-ignores`, or other means -- though that's probably not what you want to do since the code as-is is broken

---

disclaimer: I currently maintain flake8